# How to create accordion in non SXA site?

Tags: sitecore-api

We would like to create accordion in non SXA website. Also we need to include to all the options which are there in SXA, like creating new accordion element in the experience editor instead of creating in content editor.

Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: Maybe that helps? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZsZwTpLBTQ